# Is there a pin in Judo that cannot be classified as a standard pin?

Tags: judo, technique, sport, pins

I was recently inspired by this question: [Do pins in judo have to be standard pins?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/do-pins-in-judo-have-to-be-standard-pins)

The answers given are obviously correct as the Judo definition of a pin is a lot more loose than what the question suggests. However it made me wonder:

I cannot remember ever having seen a pin in Judo that was so unconventional that I was unable to classify it as one of the standard pins. Does anyone of you know of such a technique (preferably one that could reasonably used in randori or shiai)?

Comment: There are four,  arguably five **groups** of similar pins or gatame (tate-shiho, yoko-shiho, kami-shiho, kesa, (kata)). Probably every pin can be classified as belonging to one of the *groups*, but surely there are loads of different, non-standard *pins*.

Comment: My definition of standart here would be anything that belongs into any of the groups that Philip Klöcking listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most legally scoring pins come under one of the [10 osaekomi-waza classifications](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/how-are-pins-classified-in-judo/9612). However, I have seen a couple of unconventional pins which do not obviously appear to fall under any of these:

## Unconventional *osaekomi-waza*

What differentiates these from traditional pins is that tori is controlling uke from *behind*, holding from behind their head and using tension in the gi (or an inverted headlock) to pin them, as opposed to using their bodyweight on top of uke.

#### SRT / Funakubo-gatame

A technique favoured by Matsumoto Kaori and Funakubo Haruka, a variation of the "[Super Rolling Thunder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16-LQNgTnSY)" (SRT) / stomach wrap turnover. Here tori usually prevents rotation in the other direction by also holding the belt/pants of the opposite side of uke:

| Example Image | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | - [WC Seniors 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErSlsJX9oBc) - WC Juniors 2015: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qX4h8mUvw-c), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YD0jif_hqTk), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj6o9Dhm0dY) |
| [image] | A similar technique from An Baul |

#### Matsumoto headlock / Wrestling's "[Assassin](https://www.wiaawi.org/Portals/0/PDF/Sports/Wrestling/Assassin-pic-text-final.pdf)"

When going for an anaconda choke, instead of rolling to finish the submission tori can push uke back or step over them to end in a pin:

| Example Image | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | - [Dusseldorf GP 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHclPZLceHo&t=162) |

#### Sankaku holds

Some variants of pinning *sankaku* positions are (to my knowledge) not covered under the standard pin classifications, but still qualify as osaekomi.

| Example Image | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| [image: https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/79875/Daria_BILODID_UKR_Urantsetseg_MUNKHBAT_MGL_U48_World_Championships_Tokyo_2019] | - [World Championships Tokyo 2019 | Bilodid vs Munkhbat | 48kg](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/79875/Daria_BILODID_UKR_Urantsetseg_MUNKHBAT_MGL_U48_World_Championships_Tokyo_2019) - [World Championship Juniors 2017 | Zenker vs Son | 78kg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Is-Q09GcUJc) - [World Championship Juniors 2017 | Olarte vs Kolmodinova | 70kg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5DLWX4IDbc) |

#### Wrestling's ["Bow & Arrow"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQsC5D2q8f4) (["*Ashi-sankaku*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJRVTPtEozE&feature=youtu.be&t=1132))

This is a pin which seems to be inspired by wrestling's "Bow and Arrow" but with control of both legs with a triangle instead of just one (necessarily because of judo rules regarding limb control by uke in *osaekomi*).

It is taught by [Koji Komuro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJN7Wm4JMeI) and has been used to success multiple times by Miku Tashiro involving trapping uke's legs with a leg-triangle, and then controlling their upper body from the outside by holding either an arm or their neck/collar.

| Example Image | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | - [Paris 2014 | Kido vs Mushkiyev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmbYZEImEMI) - [Kuwait 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmbYZEImEMI&t=35) - [Grand Slam Tyumen 2015 | Kido vs Kulikov](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/29840/Shinji_KIDO_JPN_Dmitriy_KULIKOV_RUS_Grand_Slam_Tyumen_2015) - [Grand Slam Ekaterinburg 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmbYZEImEMI&t=110) - [Hohhot 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmbYZEImEMI&t=146) - [World Championships Chelyabinsk 2014 | Tashiro vs Gwend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmbYZEImEMI&t=180) |

## Non-scoring pins

There are a number of unconventional pins which are unclassified but are non-scoring or illegal. These also are differentiated from usual pins in that control comes from *behind* uke's body:

#### Seated on side-ribs

This pin is no longer considered valid for scoring since uke's arm is not between the legs, and thus no control over it ([IJF Referee & Coach Seminar 2016 - Part 1 (7:20:10)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLy8ggzTWpw&t=26470)).:

| Example Image | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | "This kind of osaekomi-waza is not valid and the referee must call mate if there is no progression in the action." - [IJF Sport and Organisation Rules (SOR, version 5 June 2019) (Sport Commission)](http://99e89a50309ad79ff91d-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.r14.cf3.rackcdn.com/up/2019/06/IJF_Sport_and_Organisation_Rul-1559822605.pdf) (p.117) |

#### "Crucifix"

| Example Image | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | There is also the [crucifix hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifix_position), which as far as I'm aware does not come under any of the official Kodokan pin groupings. Note: the Kodokan used to designate the collar choke executed from this position as [*jigoku-jime*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kHjF5OkwMs), but I believe it is now officially considered a variant of *okuri-eri-jime*. |
| [image: ...] | Mifune's *ura-gatame* ("Crucifix") This pin is considered non-scoring since tori's body is underneath uke's. |

#### Headlock (without arm)

Additionally there are headlock pins which are illegal due to potential danger to the neck:

| Example Image | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | "This kind of osaekomi-waza is not valid and the referee must call mate immediately." "It is never allowed to hold an osaekomi just around the head/neck without control of at least one arm." - Ibid. |

Comment: AFAIK there are are kami sankaku osae gatame and Tate sankaku osae gatame

Comment: Funakubo-gatame, Shiba-Yama Tate Gaeshi

Answer (score 2):

[*Uki gatame* is a Kodokan-classified pin](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/waza/list/#a2-2) that is neither a *shiho* nor a *kesa* type hold.  This pin is most common from the position where *tori* is attempting *ude-hishigi-juji-gatame* with both legs over *uke* and decides to change from the arm lock to a pin.

[image: uki gatame]

Personally, I would also argue that pins from a sankaku position are also not shiho holds, but the Kodokan says otherwise.