# How are pins classified in Judo?

Tags: judo, technique, pins

A number of changes have been made to Kodokan *osaekomi-waza* classification over the years; how are different pins distinguished in Judo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| Katame-waza | Variants | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **kesa-gatame** | any hold where tori holds uke diagonally controlling their head and one arm, facing uke's head | [image][image][image][image][image] |
| **kuzure-kesa-gatame** | any variant of kesa-gatame where the hold is under both arms, not diagonally across the shoulder and under one arm makura-kesa-gatame | [image][image][image] [image] |
| **ushiro-kesa-gatame** | any variant of kesa-gatame where you are facing the direction of uke's legs short-arm scissors hold | [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] |
| **kata-gatame** | pin similar to kesa-gatame but with uke's arm trapped against their neck by tori's shoulder in an arm triangle (as opposed to trapped under tori's armpit) | [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] |
| **kami-shiho-gatame** | any hold where tori holds uke facing them head on, with both arms under or over uke's arms: also includes transitions from yoko-sankaku-jime: | [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] |
| **kuzure-kami-shiho-gatame** | variant of kami-shiho-gatame with one of uke's arms trapped: | [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] |
| **yoko-shiho-gatame** | any hold where you face uke perpendicularly, controlling a leg and the head/far arm: mune-gatame: | [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] |
| **tate-shiho-gatame** | any hold where you are seated over uke's abdomen/chest controlling their head/arm(s) also includes sankaku-holds from this position | [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image: Grabbing own collar] |
| **uki-gatame** | any hold from a juji-gatame-like position any hold where you are restraining uke by putting weight on their abdomen through your knee/shin |  |
| **ura-gatame** | pins similar to *ushiro-kesa-gatame* but with control of the near leg/back facing uke | [image] [image] |